# How to configure maven autoprefixer plugin

Tags: maven, autoprefixer

I want to use the maven autoprefixer plugin => http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/autoprefixer/5.2.0

Sadly, I cannot find any documentation on how to configure that plugin.

A already followed the links on the git repo pages but I could not find any descriptions on how to run it with maven.

Did anyone use that plugin already and could provide me some useful links on how to use it? (Google did not help)

Comment: That doesn't seem like a Maven plugin that is supposed to process resources at Maven build time, but rather a JavaScript library that is packaged as a Maven dependency. http://www.webjars.org/ "WebJars are client-side web libraries (e.g. jQuery & Bootstrap) packaged into JAR (Java Archive) files."

Comment: So I cannot use it like I thought I could?

Comment: How did you think of using it? As part of your Maven build?

Comment: I think that it is a two step process. First you config grunt to execute autoprefixer (https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#grunt) then you execute grunt via Maven : http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: @Ates Goral: yes, that was exactly, what I wanted to do.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It seems crazy to add Grunt to a project just to use autoprefixer. I just wanna process my CSS the same way I do using a SASS maven plugin.

Comment: @dwjohnston, did you ever figure out a way to do this without Grunt?